# How to find name of tables for which you are the owner in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

How to find name of tables for which you are the owner in *pgAdmin 4*?

Comment: There does not appear to be a GIS component to your question which I think would be better researched/asked at the [dba.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
select * from pg_tables where tableowner='user'
```